# Check if a string contains a set of characters at the end of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have a simple problem, but has become a troublesome problem:

```
$variable="This is some text***";

if (strpos($variable,'*') !== false) {
   echo 'found *';
} else {
   echo 'not found *';
}
```

But it will find a `*` in the text no matter how many `*`s there are.

I want to make it only can be found by searching specified star, *** (three stars) instead only * (one star).

Comment: if starts found than what will u do?? remove?? or nothing?

Comment: strpos($variable,'***') !== false

Comment: devpro : that just dummy code, my real code will be there just want to classified text with containing star, because strpos will find is there is contain matched char, not a containing char, well it may confusing.

Deep : it will be trouble some if I have many data contain * single, ** double, *** triple stars, all data will be matched, but I wanted only specified star founded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it even more strict matching, that you only want it to match a string that contains `***` at the end of the string you can use regex, so,

```
if (preg_match('~[^*]\*{3}$~', $str)) {
    print "Valid";
}
```

What this says is when a string has 3 stars at the end and there are no asterisks before those 3 stars then it will be true.  Change the `3` to a `2` or `1` or whatever number of stars you want to match.

`[^*]` means that there can be a character but it cannot be a star that is followed by 3 stars.  `\*{3}` means it will match 3 stars.  The backslash is to escape asterisk for the pattern match and 3 is the number of total stars.

It could be a function like this:

```
function starMatch($str, $count) {
    return (bool)preg_match('~[^*]\*{'.$count.'}$~', $str);
}
```

And called like this:

```
starMatch($str, 1);  // matches *
starMatch($str, 2);  // matches **
starMatch($str, 3);  // matches ***
```

Comment: I ask this question because the problem is, when you have many data with
sometext*, sometext** , sometext***